# How to hide content of .ts in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, abstraction

I'm writing a calculation logic on button click which can be viewed in main.ts even when build in prod mode. How can I hide the calculation written inside the event method of .ts file

In .html - `<button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:15px;align-items:center" (click)="Calculate()">Calculate</button>`

In .ts - `Calculate() { // some calculation logic which I want to hide and don't want to expose to front-end user through dev tools}`

Also the values are calculated based on input form user enters as an input, hence calculation logic also contains the properties in 2 way data binding.

Comment: You can use `@internal` in the JSDoc and `--stripInternal` in the config to not output definitions when compiled, but you cannot remove it from the actual source code otherwise it won't work in the browser.

Comment: reach for `obfuscate`, but I tell you this, you can never hide your frontend code, even with obfuscated code, it makes reading/reversing the code a little harder but eventually, it will be deciphered